# iPad variable ping problem

Tags: ipad, ios, networking

Hee,

I'm working on an iPad App and i have a problem with one of my iPads. I'm making an network based application for the iPad, so my network has to work correctly.

When i ping 2 of them i will get a decent ping result.
[image]

One one iPad i have my problem, look at this ping:
[image]

As you can see my ping results are really variable. But when you look closer, you see that some packets have exactly(+/-) 1 second difference. See packets: (1&2),(3&4)(8&9) (etc).

Does any one had the same problem with an ipad? Or solved it? 
A colleague of mine said it could be a driver problem. Can that be? The one with the problems is from mid 2010 and the others are manufactured in the end of 2010. (All devices are on 4.2.1)

Thanks a lot. It's kinda killing me.